# PHP file upload on Ipad

Tags: php, iphone, ipad, file-upload

Good Morning ya'll

I have this php file upload and works great on a computer, but last night it got tested on an ipad and it didn't work....I am not sure if this a complex answer and an easy one...Probably complex...but if someone can point me in the right direction that would be great.. here is my code

```
<div class="content">
<form action="Gallery.php?action=insertsubmitImage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="500000000000">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $array['id']; ?>" name="id" />
<p>
<label for="image">Image</label>
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
</p>

<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add" />
</p>

</form>

</div><!--content-->
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks for your time :)

Comment: What does "not work" mean exactly?!

Comment: it wont let me select a file to upload.

Comment: Why exactly are there two downvotes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mobile Safari has no ability to upload files (and iOS does not have a traditional file system exposed to the user anyway).

It would be nice if it exposed (for instance) the photo library, but that isn't a feature that Apple have implemented.

Comment: Check out Apple discussion as well: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3043183?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

The iPad (iOS actually) doesn't support file uploads. Unfortunately there's nothing you can do about it. iOS 6 will when it comes out for basic things like images. A workaround for the problem is to allow the user to email a file attachment to your website at a special email address that uses a php script to add the image to your gallery.

[This should get you started on parsing email](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/extract-attachments-email-php-imap/) if you go that route.

Comment: Thanks...I dont think its the path I wont to go down.

Answer (score 2):

Mobile Safari does not support file uploads. This may be because iOS does not have a file system.

I think iOS 6 will have this feature when it comes out this Fall.